# Outlook autocomplete names keep reappearing after I delete them

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, autocomplete

This is an NK2 file that has been copied from a previous incarnation of my system after a clean wipe. Autocomplete works great, but whenever I delete an old name in Outlook (select the name in the autocomplete list and press Del), it's back whenever I relaunch Outlook.

New names DO get added however, so it's not like the NK2 file is read-only or something.

Windows 7, Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if your NK2 file got corrupt.

There are 2 methods to fix this.

1. Remove the NK2 file and restart outlook, so the file is being rebuild. This of course means that auto-complete will have no email addresses until you populate it again.
2. Download [NirSoft's NK2 Editor](http://nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html) and remove the invalid nk2 entries there.

Comment: Nice! I'll try that and report back.